# Extracting lines from a text in python

Tags: python, startswith, writefile

I am trying to extract the lines that start with this entries and create a new file. This is what I have:

```
def ReadFileContents():
    file_content = open('Testing.pdb')
    all_file_content = file_content.readlines()
    list3 = []
    for line in all_file_content:
        if line.startswith('TER'):`enter code here`
            list3.append(line)
            if line.startswith('HETATM'):
                list3.apped(line)
                if line.startswith('CONECT'):
                    list3.append(line)
                    if line.startswith('MASTER'):
                        list3.append(line)
                        if line.startswith('END'):
                            list3.append(line)
            file = open('list3.txt', 'w')
            for line in list3:
                file.write(line + '\n')
            file.close()
```

ReadFileContents()

The problem is that only creates the list3.txt file with the lines that start with TER. Any ideas why?

Thanks, 
Pedro

Comment: Because you only matching lines that are starting with TER :) The inner conditions of `line.startswith('TER')` are absurd.

Answer (score 1):

Spaces in the beginning of the line denote a code block level in python.
Suppose you have the following code:

```
if A:
    #do something
    if B:
        #do another thing
```

`another thing` will be done only if A condition is `True`.

```
def ReadFileContents():
    file_content = open('Testing.pdb')
    all_file_content = file_content.readlines()
    list3 = []
    for line in all_file_content:
        if line.startswith('TER'):
            list3.append(line)
        if line.startswith('HETATM'):
            list3.apped(line)
        if line.startswith('CONECT'):
            list3.append(line)
        if line.startswith('MASTER'):
            list3.append(line)
        if line.startswith('END'):
            list3.append(line)
    file = open('list3.txt', 'w')
    for line in list3:
        file.write(line + '\n')
    file.close()
```

Comment: PS @Vishnu Upadhyay's advice to use `elif` is better than using single `if` statements,  since it will do less condition-execution job. I've explained the essence of the problem you have in your code. Vishnu's answer should be accepted and used in real program. Not only because of elif-statements but also because of exploiting `with` statement which is a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

You better use `elif` rather than `nested if`.And its always better to use `context manager` `with` to open the file and you don't need to `close` the file manually.

change this:-

```
file_content = open('Testing.pdb')
all_file_content = file_content.readlines()
```

to this:-

```
with open('Testing.pdb') as file_content:
```

Then complete code is:-

```
def ReadFileContents():
    list3 = []
    with open('Testing.pdb') as file_content: # Use `with`.
        for line in file_content.readlines():      
            if line.startswith('TER'):
                list3.append(line)
            elif line.startswith('HETATM'):
                list3.append(line)
            elif line.startswith('CONECT'):
                list3.append(line)
            elif line.startswith('MASTER'):
              list3.append(line)
            elif line.startswith('END'):
               list3.append(line)
    with open('list3.txt', 'w') as f:
        for line in list3:
            f.write(line + '\n')

        #Read the file
         f.seek(0)
         print f.read()

ReadFileContents()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def ReadFileContents():
file_content = open('Testing.pdb')
all_file_content = file_content.readlines()
list3 = []
for line in all_file_content:
        m=re.match(r"^(?:TER|HETATM|CONECT|MASTER|END).*$,line)
        if m:
            list3.append(m.group())





file = open('list3.txt', 'w')
for line in list3:
      file.write(line + '\n')
file.close()
```

You can use `re` to get what you want.It is more scalable too.